# Error in executing mysql query in php

Tags: mysql, php

My sql query in php is as below:

```
mysql_query("insert into tbl_features (img_id,features_1,features_2,features_3,features_4,features_5,features_6,features_7,features_8,features_9,features_10,features_11,features_12,features_13,features_14,features_15,features_16,features_17) VALUES ($datas[$k],$contentsarray[19],$contentsarray[20],$contentsarray[21],$contentsarray[22],$contentsarray[23],$contentsarray[24],$contentsarray[25],$contentsarray[26],$contentsarray[27],$contentsarray[28],$contentsarray[29],$contentsarray[30],$contentsarray[32],$contentsarray[33],$contentsarray[34],$contentsarray[35],$contentsarray[36] )") or die (mysql_error());
```

While executing it I get the error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1.0E-6 )' at line 1

It only inserts 13 datas when it shoudl insert 30,000. i cannot figure out the problem over here. 1.0E-6 is the last data of the 14th column. So is the bracket the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You have to put `'` around varchar data

```
mysql_query("insert into tbl_features (img_id,features_1,features_2,features_3,features_4,features_5,features_6,features_7,features_8,features_9,features_10,features_11,features_12,features_13,features_14,features_15,features_16,features_17) 
VALUES ('$datas[$k]','$contentsarray[19]','$contentsarray[20]','$contentsarray[21]','$contentsarray[22]'
,'$contentsarray[23]','$contentsarray[24]','$contentsarray[25]','$contentsarray[26]'
,'$contentsarray[27]','$contentsarray[28]','$contentsarray[29]','$contentsarray[30]',
'$contentsarray[32]','$contentsarray[33]','$contentsarray[34]','$contentsarray[35]'
,'$contentsarray[36]' )") or die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: Thanks I had tried putting ' this too but it didn't work at that time now when i try it again it is okay. I dont know the reason anyways thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you need to put `'` around varchar` data

whenever you are inserting varchar data put those data in single quotes.

like  `('$datas[$k]','$contentsarray[19]','$contentsarray[20]'...................`

Answer (score 0):

When you use `array` in `double quotes` you should surround them with `braces{}`
Try this

```
mysql_query("insert into tbl_features (img_id,features_1,features_2,features_3,features_4,features_5,features_6,features_7,features      8,features_9,features_10,features_11,features_12,features_13,features_14,features_15,features_16,features_17) 
VALUES ('{$datas[$k]}','{$contentsarray[19]}','{$contentsarray[20]}',-----") or die (mysql_error());
```